# Rhyming Riley Riddle Ra

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix wants something gone,
>
> My suffix that is now turned on!
>
> My infix is a well known zone,
>
> I am something that is unknown!

Hint:

> The last line is part of the riddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you might be

> a question?

My prefix wants something gone,

> A *quest* to rid the world of ... something ..... or (see comments) to find ... something

My suffix that is now turned on!

> An *ion* is charged -> turned on!

My infix is a well known zone,

> *EST* -> Eastern Standard Time (thanks to Mazurka Fahr for the UTC example)

I am something that is unknown!

> We ask questions about things that are unknown!

Comment: @riskymysteries Hfr bs gur jbeq "Tbar" yvxr gung vzcyvrf vg jnf fbzrguvat gung jnf gurer orsber, ohg ab ybatre vf...

Comment: Following what Weckar E. wrote, there are at least two possible constructions: rot13('jnagf fbzrguvat _gung vf_ tbar' be 'jnagf fbzrguvat _gb or_ tbar' [v.r. gb or erzbirq]) but both imply movement in time or space. I've updated the answer to address both meanings.

Answer (score 13):

Wait, are you

> Goo

My prefix wants something gone,

> Go!

My suffix that is now turned on!

> O, on a power switch, means off. You just toggled it, so it now on (I).

My infix is a well known zone,

> O, for Ozone

I am something that is unknown!

> I don't even want to know what most goo is...

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be

> x.

*My prefix wants something gone,*

> When you use **ex** as a prefix, it means you're talking about some former thing which is now gone.

*My suffix that is now turned on!*

> When you use **X** as a suffix, [it can be](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/358192/87724) short for "extra", meaning something special to turn you on.

*My infix is a well known zone,*

> X marks the spot.

*I am something that is unknown!*

> In maths, $x$ is often used for an unknown quantity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be

> uninvestigated

*My prefix wants something gone,*

> to uninvest Is to withdraw your stake in something.

*My suffix that is now turned on!*

> gated describes a pathway that can be open or closed, on or off.

*My infix is a well known zone,*

> if something has been investigated it is well known

*I am something that is unknown!*

> uninvestigated is unknown

Answer (score 2):

You might be

> Outcome

My prefix wants something gone,

> Out!

My suffix that is now turned on!

> Me! I am excited to solve this riddle

My infix is a well known zone,

> UTC, the time zone

I am something that is unknown!

> The answer to this riddle

Answer (score 1):

Another stab in the dark

> Hint.

My prefix wants something gone,

> Hi, to say hello is to want unacquaintedness to be gone

My suffix that is now turned on!

> int. is a an abbreviation of internal, the internal connection between the two parties has turned on after their hello

My infix is a well known zone,

> in, inside is a well known place

I am something that is unknown!

> hint, the hint is hidden by a spoiler tag

Answer (score 1):

> Are you...

> Antimatter ?

> My prefix wants something gone,

> Anti could imply being against something (wanting something gone);

> My suffix that is now turned on!

> ER (emergency room), turned on due to the current situation with COVID;

> My infix is a well known zone,

> Matt as in Matt Zone, a well know Ohio city councilman.

> I am something that is unknown!

> Antimatter is still in its early stages of study and dus, still unknown.